# ERRO C++ - [Error] ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++

Estou aprendendo C++ e copiei um código da internet e dei uma modificada nele, mas ele apresenta o Erro ao compilar - [Error] ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive].

Código:

```cpp
include iostream

include stdio.h

define SIZE 200

char nome[SIZE][50];

char sexo[SIZE][50];

int rg[SIZE][50];

int cpf[SIZE][50];

int tel[SIZE][50];

int idade[SIZE][50];

int op;

void cadastro();

void pesquisa();

int main(void) {

    cadastro();

    pesquisa();

}



void cadastro(){

    static int linha;

    do{

        printf("\nDigite o nome: ");

        scanf("%s", &nome[linha]);

        printf("\nDigite o sexo [F/M]: ");

        scanf("%s", &sexo[linha]);

        printf("\nDigite o RG: ");

        scanf("%d", &rg[linha]);

        printf("\nDigite o CPF: ");

        scanf("%d", &cpf[linha]);

        printf("\nDigite a idade: ");

        scanf("%d", &idade[linha]);

        printf("\nDigite o telefone: ");

        scanf("%d", &tel[linha]);

        printf("\nDigite 1 para continuar ou 2 para sair: ");

        scanf("%d", &op);

        linha++;

    }while(op==1);

}



void pesquisa(){

    int cpfPesquisa;

    int i;

    do{

        printf("\nDigite o CPF que deseja buscar: ");

        scanf("%d", &cpfPesquisa);

        for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++){

            if(cpf[i]==cpfPesquisa){

                printf("\nNome: %s\nSexo: %s\nCPF: %d\nRG: %d\nIdade: %d\nTelefone: %d", nome[i], 

sexo[i], cpf[i], rg[i], idade[i], tel[i]);


            }

        }

    printf("\nDigite 1 para continuar pesquisando: ");

    scanf("%d", &op);

    }while(op==1);  

}
```

Comment: Apesar de você informar C++ seu código está em C. Aqui: `scanf("%s", &nome[linha]);` e aqui: `scanf("%s", &sexo[linha]);` não tem este `& ` pois são strings. Note que você não atribuiu um valor inicial à variável `linha`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perceba que `int cpf[SIZE][50]` é um array 2D. Por isso, ao indexar apenas uma vez o resultado vai ser um ponteiro para inteiro (visto que o array 1D resultante degenera para um ponteiro), e não um inteiro. Isso explica o erro de comparar um ponteiro e um inteiro na linha com `cpf[i] == cpfPesquisa`. Se você indexar mais uma vez aí sim vai obter um inteiro.

Comment: Teria como mandar um exemplo, pois não manjo muito de linguagem C.